# Bind a socket to interface and not on IP

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm writing a packet sniffer and I am using the Socket.BeginReceive to receive packets send to the local machine. Using Socket.Bind I can connect to a NIC interface based on the IPEindPoint IpAdress. However in certain cases, there is no IP address configured to a NIC (the NIC is using a native driver to send IP TCP/UDP packets).

How do I connect Socket.Bind to a NIC without IP Address?

Comment: Never heard of a method that would send IP packets without having and address of its own..

Comment: So the NIC has a special driver called RAWNIC kernel driver (Microsoft) and has a seperate configuration file where the NIC is configured. It does have an IP address but it is not visible for the system. 
`code`IPHostEntry HosyEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()));`code`  is used to show IP addresses to bind to, but this doesnt show the rawnic IP. Also a ipconfig /all will not show the NIC. Hard coded binding on the IP also does not work. That is why i need to bind on the interface not the IP.

Comment: Have you considered pcap.net (http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)?