# Bind a socket to specific interface targeting remote host

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, bind

**The Environment**

Imagine Three Machines in two different LANs:

```
Machine1 (1 NIC) : NIC_IP=10.1.1.1
Machine2 (2 NIC) : NIC(1)_IP = 10.3.3.3 ; NIC(2)_IP= 10.1.1.1
Machine3 (1 NIC) : NIC_IP=10.3.3.3
```

The LAN are configured this way:

```
LAN(1) = Machine1.NIC, Machine2.NIC1
LAN(2) = Machine3.NIC, Machine2.NIC2
```

Thus only Machine2 is a member of both LANs.

---

**The Question**

Now we want to establish one connection from Machine2.Nic2 to Machine3.NIC. That is a connection from 10.1.1.1 on machine2 to 10.3.3.3 on machine3.

How can we tell the TCP/IP stack of Machine2 to find destination address on LAN(2) and not on the localhost!?
(Apparently if Machine3 initiates the connection, the desired endpoints would participate in connection [but machine2 is the initiator in our case])

---

**Usage Scenario (The one I WANT)**

```
[Machine3=] ______LAN 2 _____ [=Machine2=]_______LAN 1________ [=Machine1]
   |                                                               |
   |_ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ virtually connected_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

Consider Machine2 as to somehow provide a kind of "Bridging Service" between LAN(1) and LAN(2) for the communication of Machine1 and Machine3. In this way machine1 tries to connect to machine3 (thinking as if they are in the same LAN), but here comes the machin2 in the middle with the desired IP of machine3 visible to machine1. In this process Machine2 can hand the data from machine1 to machine3 (hence kind of selective manual bridging thing).

---

**After Thinking more...(a workaround)**

```
[Machine3=] __LAN 2 __ [=Machine2A=]__LAN3__ [=Machine2B=]___LAN 1___ [=Machine1]
   |                                                                       |
   |_ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ virtually connected_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|

Machine2B (2 NIC) : NIC(1)_IP = 10.3.3.3 ; NIC(2)_IP= 10.x.y.z
Machine2A (2 NIC) : NIC(1)_IP = 10.w.s.t ; NIC(2)_IP= 10.1.1.1
```

I see that it is possible to achieve the same by adding another machine and another LAN to the scenario [However it is currently just a workaround (at least not the answer right now)]

---

PS: There is [a question somehow in the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313484/bind-a-socket-to-interface-and-not-on-ip) which differs in that they are writing a packet sniffer and probably not establishing connections (just reading / injecting packets, etc) and they do not assign IP address to their interface and thus they don't have two distinct destinations one in their localhost and another in the LAN.

Comment: Unless routing is enabled, you will not be able to connect to Machine3 using Machine2.NIC2, since it is in a different subnet. Is there a reason you do not want to use NIC1 instead ?

Comment: Machine 2 shares the same IP address as Machine 1 and Machine 3.  I don't think that's the configuration you want.  I assume you want machine 2 to have IP addresses of 10.3.3.4 and 10.1.1.2.

Comment: @selbie: Thanks for the comment. I have added a "Usage Scenario" section to the question text to describe my intention better.

Comment: @T.Fabre: Well, that might be the point. May be something "out of the programming" context shall be considered on Machine2 (The routing table you told...)

Comment: I think you just want machine 2 to be configured as a router and then have routing rules for all three machines. At this point, this is more of a system administration question than a programming question.

Comment: @selbie: My point is that the "program" shall perform the service not the operating system. You may consider the program as a "Configurable Application Layer Router" (Since it may decide based on the content of packets [not just the src/dst information] for forwarding them or not).

Comment: I have added and described a workaround to the question text which uses 4 computers and 3 LANs and 4 different IP addresses being used. 
But I want to achieve that with 3 computers, 2 LANS and 3 IP addresses :-)

Comment: I think it would be helpful to explain what you are really trying to do and what the goal of your project is.  I've written TCP proxies before and will be happy to help as best I can.

Comment: @selbie: This would be a "machine-in-the-middle" user-level proxy service (transparent for connection parties)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that you have machine2 on identical IP addresses as other machines on LAN1 and LAN2.  That's not going to work. You can't have two hosts on the same subnet with the same IP address. Otherwise, all the hosts will get confused.

I don't know if that's really what you intended or was just an oversight in your description.

Now if the following was your configuration

```
LAN1: Network: 10.1.1.0 (8-bit subnet)
LAN2: Network: 10.3.3.0 (8-bit subnet)

Machine1: 10.1.1.1 on LAN1
Machine2: 10.1.1.2 on LAN1 and 10.3.3.4 on LAN2
Machine3: 10.3.3.3 on LAN2
```

With this configuration, you really don't have to do anything special with your socket listening code to connect through the right NIC. For outbound client connections, the routing table will do the right thing and choose the appropriate interface to connect through. Anytime you create a socket, you can specify a specific port to bind to, but don't specify anything other than 0 (INADDR_ANY) for the IP to bind to.  Everything will "just work" if your routing table is configured.

```
int localport = /* 0 for clients, a specific port for server sockets */
socket.Bind(new IPEndpoint(0,localport));
```

Comment: But I thought having two identical IPs on two different physical LANs would be OK.

Comment: Oh I see, you have the IPs flipped between the two NICs.  And it's a 24-bit subnet.  That might work, but I think you are better off just configuring Machine2 as a router and having route rules for all three machines.

Comment: But router is normally layer three (IP Layer). I want to program, lets say, a "TCP router"

Comment: @AliFakoor It's only OK if they don't have to communicate with each other. If they do, it isn't. The simple solution is to use three IP addresses instead of one.

Comment: @EJP: Tnx for the comment. In fact,  the two identical IP addresses are not going to communicating with each other. 


    IP1 communicates with IP2 in one LAN; 
    IP2 communicates with IP3 in another LAN; 
    where IP1 , IP2 and IP3 are different (Thus having the three addresses you mentioned);

Comment: @AliFakoor They can't be identical and different at the same time. Please clarify.

Comment: @EJP: Well, yes you are right. I got a little mixed up while explaining (only 2 IPs exist). 

The fact is that only different IP addresses communicate with each other (in the same LAN) and we don't have Identical IP addresses in any given LAN (but identical IPs are possible in different LANs).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in writing this batch script. 
This will add static MAC addresses to the arp table and adds route-table entries. For correctly setting the default gateway in route entries I had to introduce two new arbitrary IP addresses in other class.
Moreover I unchecked the "Automatic metric" on the NICs of the MAchine2 and set it to 30.

The ID of NIC is the one shown in "route print"

```
SET ID_Nic1=0x3
SET ID_Nic2=0x10005

SET IF_Left=%ID_Nic1%
SET IF_Right=%ID_Nic2%

SET IP_Left=10.1.1.1
SET IP_Right=10.3.3.3

SET AUX_Left=172.16.1.1
SET AUX_Right=172.16.3.3

SET MAC_Left=00-11-22-33-44-55
SET MAC_Right=66-77-88-99-11-22


REM Delete all ARP entries
arp -d *


arp -s %IP_Left% %MAC_Left% %AUX_Left%
arp -s %IP_Right% %MAC_Right% %AUX_Right%


ROUTE ADD %IP_Left% MASK 255.255.255.255 %AUX_Left% METRIC 1 IF %IF_Left%
ROUTE ADD %IP_Right% MASK 255.255.255.255 %AUX_Right% METRIC 1 IF %IF_Right%
```